# How to extend an abstract class with factory constructor?

Tags: interface, dart, abstract-class

The situation is following:

```dart
abstract class A {
  void doSomething() => print('Do something..');
}

class B implements A {
  @override
  void doSomething() => print('Do something already..');
}

class C extends A {
}
```

I have an abstract class A.
Class B implements A. Therefore it overrides doSomething() method. Class C extends A.

Everything works fine, until I'm adding factory constructor to class A:

```dart
abstract class A {
  factory A() => new B();

  void doSomething() => print('Do something..');
}
```

This leads to an error in my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA):

> The generative constructor expected, but factory found

My first idea was to create constructor for class C where I would call factory constructor for A. Is it possible to do?

I got the same problem when I try to extend Exception class. It also has a factory constructor:

```dart
abstract class Exception {
  factory Exception([var message]) => new _ExceptionImplementation(message);
}
```

Thats why to create my custom exception I have to implement Exception class instead of extending it and it really confuses me.

I also would like to clarify one terminology question.
Can I say that from point of view of B class, A is an interface, so B is implementing interface A.
However, from point of view of C class, A is an abstract class so C is extending abstract class A. Are these statements correct?

Thank you.

Dmitry.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If a class has no constructor a generative constructor is implicitly added. If a class has an explicit constructor no generative constructor is added.
You have two options.

- make the factory constructor a named factory constructor and add a normal constructor

```dart
abstract class A {
  void doSomething() => print('Do something..');
  factory A.name() => new B();
  A();
}
```

- or make the normal constructor named and call it explicitly from the extending class

```dart
abstract class A {
  void doSomething() => print('Do something..');
  factory A() => new B();
  A.protected();
}

class C extends A {
  C() : super.protected();
}
```

try at [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=28a51cfb570f790146a2)

Your statement is right. If you implement a class it acts as an interface and if you extend it it acts as a base class.

Comment: Plus, of course, "class B implements A {...}. Then you can say, "B b = new A()"?

Comment: @TomRussell No you can't do that. There are two problems in that line. 1. You can't instantiate an abstract class using its constructor like `A()`. 2. Even if it had been a concrete class, you still can't do that because the instance of `A` can't be assigned to `B` although the reverse is true i.e. `A a = B()`.

Comment: @Günter, I don't see that error anymore in latest Dart SDKs. You don't need to create any dummy constructor for that. If you are not maintaining your Dart answers, you can ignore this comment. But if you are, then I'd like to know is there something I am not doing right. Here's the code on [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/ab15cdb4f61279ca73393aa564f8062c?null_safety=true).

Comment: I don't think there has anything changed. I'd need to see a full example to understand your situation.

Comment: I didn't receive the notification as you forgot to use `@` while replying. What I was saying is, in the OP's 2nd code snippet, he gets an error on doing `factory A() => new B();`, but I'm not seeing that error anymore. I shared the DartPad link in my previous comment where I'm actually doing the same thing but there are no errors. So, what I wanted to say is you don't need to provide any constructor in `A` abstract class to just do `factory A() => new B();`.

Comment: @iDecode I don't remember seeing this error, but might have been a bug. Thanks for the Dartpad, I missed the link. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know it works but it solves my problem. And I know there are a lot solution for this may be this solution worst. :) but I want to share with you

Sometimes backend API returns same model but different by values.
like this.

```dart
Map<String,dynamic> map1 = {
  "version": "2.16.0",
  "language_1":"Dart",
  "framework_1":"Flutter",
};


Map<String,dynamic> map2 = {
  "version" : "10.0.1",
  "language_2":"javaScript",
  "framework_2":"NodeJs",
};
```

I need `D` model so extends other models from `D`

```dart
class D{
  D({
    this.language,
    this.frameWork,
    this.version,
  });
  String? language;
  String? frameWork;
  String? version;
}
```

Extends models from `D`

```dart
class A extends D{
  A();
  
  factory A.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) => C.fromJsonForA(json);

}


class B extends D{
  B();
  
 factory B.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) => C.fromJsonForB(json);
}
```

And write the `factory` constructor in other class `C`

```dart
class C extends D implements B,A{
  C({
    String? language,
    String? frameWork,
    String? version,
  }):super(
    language:language,
    frameWork:frameWork,
    version:version,
  );
  
  factory C.fromJsonForB(Map<String,dynamic> json){
    final c = C.protected(json);
    c.frameWork = json['framework_2'];
    c.language = json['language_2'];
    return c;
  }
  
  
  factory C.fromJsonForA(Map<String,dynamic> json){
    final c = C.protected(json);
    c.frameWork = json['framework_1'];
    c.language = json['language_1'];
    return c;
  }
  
  
  factory C.protected(Map<String,dynamic> json){
    return C(
      version: json["version"],
    );
  }
}
```

And I used :)

```dart
  A modelA = A.fromJson(map1);
  B modelB = B.fromJson(map2);
```

```dart
class Example {
  Example._();
  
  static printModel(D model){
    print("${model.language} : ${model.frameWork} version : ${model.version}");
  }
}
```